# Why new[-1] generates segfault, while new[-2] throws bad_alloc?

Tags: c++, new-operator, negative-number, bad-alloc

I tried to test `bad_alloc` exception by passing some negative arguments to `new[]`. When passing small negative numbers I get what I hoped for - a `bad_alloc`. However, when passing `-1`, I can see that my object is constructed thousands of times (I print static counter in constructor) and the application terminates with segfault.

`new[]` converts signed integer to `size_t`, so `-1` is the max of `size_t` and `-2` is the `maximum - 1` and so on.

So why `new[]` throws exception when receiving some huge number, but tries to allocate when receiving the max of `size_t`? What is the difference between `1111...1` and `1111...0` for `new[]`? :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which compiler/compiler's version/OS/...

Comment: That time I missed the answers because StackOverflow doesn't send me any notifications, and now I cannot reproduce the problem... I regret I hadn't generated core dumps and didn't investigate it... Now I cannot reproduce the problem - passing -1 to 'new' seems to work and throws exception, while passing max int allocates a lot of objects but doesn't segfault. I'm starting to think that the problem was somewhere else... I give a plus to Mystical for his try.

Answer (score 18):

**Here's my wild guess:**

In lot of implementations, the allocator will place some meta-data next to the allocated region.
(For example, the size of the allocation.) So you are, in effect, allocating more than what you asked for.

Let's assume `size_t` is 32-bits. Compiled for 32-bits.

---

When you do:

```
int *array = new int[-1];
```

The `-1` becomes `-1 * 4 bytes = 4294967292` (after overflow). But if the allocator implementation puts 4-bytes of meta-data next to the allocated region. The actual size becomes:

```
4294967292 + 4 bytes = 0 bytes (after overflow)
```

So `0` bytes is actually allocated.

**When you try to access the memory, you segfault since you go out-of-bounds immediately.**

---

Now let's say you do:

```
int *array = new int[-2];
```

The `-2` becomes `-2 * 4 bytes = 4294967288` (after overflow). Append 4-bytes of meta-data and you get `4294967288 + 4 = 4294967292`.

**When the allocator requests `4294967292` bytes from the OS, it is denied. So it throws `bad_alloc`.**

---

So basically, it's possible that `-1` and `-2` makes the difference between whether or not it will overflow after the allocator appends its meta-data.

Comment: I have never seen such a buggy implementation in the wild though

Comment: +1.  "When you try to access the memory" - "you" being `new[]`  moving on to loop over the elements it thinks it allocated space for, calling placement `new` to invoke the constructor on each....

Comment: @PlasmaHH That's what I'm thinking too. I'm trying to find a source that tells me whether any of this is undefined behavior. But I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: @TonyDelroy: Which makes me think... the OP said that he can see thousands of objects being constructed. So the question is how likely it is that allocating 0 bytes will lead to a pointer pointing to something where you can allocate thousands of objects. It would have been useful, had the OP mentioned his platform.

Comment: `operator new` is required to return a non-null pointer, even if the requested size is 0. Then you are free to overwrite the rest of the heap...

Comment: @BoPersson, you're not really free to overwrite the rest of the heap.  Writing beyond the end of a memory buffer allocated with new results in undefined behaviour.  If you're returned a pointer to a zero byte buffer, you basically can't read or write anything there.  All you can do is use the pointer as a unique value (amongst other pointers) and delete it.

Comment: @james - I missed the smiley after the dots. :-) It was supposed to be an "explanation" on how the compiler could construct "thousands of objects" in zero allocated bytes.

Comment: @James: "you're not really free" / "undefined behaviour" - absolutely true that the behaviour is not guaranteed - the discussion is just about whether the likely implementation on real systems is reconcilable with the observed behaviour.  It's entirely believable that on the OP's system a heap allocation for 0 bytes returned an address at which thousands of objects could be constructed before the segfault, as described in the question.

Comment: @BoPersson Ah.  Fair enough.  :)

Comment: @TonyDelroy: Actually, the question is how big is the object being constructed by the OP's test code?  If it's the same size as size_t then I would expect exactly the behaviour described by Mystical.  The new array operator needs to store the size of the array next to the array itself so it knows how many objects to destroy when deleting the array. `new o[-1]` where `sizeof(o)==sizeof(size_t)` will attempt to allocate exactly zero bytes - something most memory allocators can do.  `new o[-2]` will attempt to allocate 2^32-4 bytes, which will fail on a 32-bit system and thus throw bad_alloc.

Comment: If it manages to allocate 0 bytes but assumes there are 2^32-1 objects, it will most probably crash after initialising ~1000 objects.  Ie when the next page boundary is met.

Comment: @James: I agree the size is a question and factor - though not "the question".  Also agree that while the new operator doesn't *need* to store the array size next to the array, that's the implementation choice Mystical's exploring.  Anyway, there's absolutely nothing to say that it should crash at the first page boundary - it's common for an allocation library to use `sbreak()` to allocate large numbers of pages to heap in each call, and unspecified whether the heap grows upward or downward in a way that means earlier memory allocation may be overwritten by the run-away constructions....